# map function in ES5 vs ES6

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code for removing duplicates from an array of object in ES6 as follows

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
}
```

I am trying to understand the map function here using ES5 standards. Is there any other way to better write the above code in ES5 format? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just change the arrow functions, nothing else in your code is ES6+

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am kind of confused with the syntax, like where the indexOf is getting operated on and what is getting returned etc. filter function is clear but I I have issue understanding map function here.

Comment: The `.indexOf` is being called on the previous expression.

Comment: `return arr.map(function(mapObj) { return mapObj[prop]; }).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;`

Comment: Or simpler `var props = arr.map(function(mapObj) { return mapObj[prop]; });` then `return props.indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;`

Comment: BTW `removeDuplicates` can further be optimized by using `findIndex` instead of `map/indexOf` combo:

Comment: `function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {     return myArr.filter(function(obj, pos) {                
        return myArr.findIndex(function(findObj) {          
            return findObj[prop] === obj[prop];             
        }) === pos;                                         
    });                                                      }                                                   `